# Parent passes state to child - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ObjectList has an array of objects that get rendered as a list. When the user clicks a list item, that object is sent back to ObjectEditor so the user can view it and continue editing. The problem is that I'm not sure how to pass that object to ObjectEditor because the click event is taking place in ObjectList.

My initial solution was to pass it to ObjectEditor as props and use the componentWillReceiveProps method to update ObjectEditors state. However, that solution wasn't practical because I don't want it to update every time the props change. Is there a better way?

I'm new to React so I'd like to avoid using Redux for now until I've covered React.

I've heavily cut down the code for clarity.

ObjectList:

```
      constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = { objects: [
          {title: '', items: [], anotherThing:''},
          {title: '', items: [], anotherThing:''}
        ]}
      }

      viewObject = (index) => {
      let object = {...this.state.object[index]};
     // Then some code that passes the object to the ObjectEditor Component
       }

      render(){
        return(
          <div>

           <li key={index} onClick={ () => this.viewObject(index) } >
           // A list of titles from state
           </li>

          <ObjectEditor />
          </div>
        )
      }
```

ObjectEditor:

```
       constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {title:'', items: [], anotherThing:''}
       }

    // various event handlers that update the state based off form inputs

      render(){
        return(
          <div> 

            // Various form fields which get pushed to state

            <button>Save & Add New</button> 

            // function that maps through state and renders it to the page
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to have the parent component handle all the state and logic, and keep the `ObjectEditor` component a simple presentation component with no logic or state of its own. It would look a little something like this.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            objects: [
                { title: '', items: [], anotherThing: '' },
                { title: '', items: [], anotherThing: '' }
            ],
            editObject: {},
        }
    }

    viewObject = (index) => {
        let object = { ...this.state.object[index] };
        this.setState({editObject: object}); // sets the state if the clicked item.
        // Then some code that passes the object to the ObjectEditor Component
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        // handle change
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <li key={index} onClick={() => this.viewObject(index)} >
                // A list of titles from state
                </li>

                <ObjectEditor viewObject={this.state.viewObject} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class ObjectEditor extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            // render some sort of editor
            // display data based on the props passed down
            // when user edits in the form, call up to the parent's change handler
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ObjectEditor has to have state because it uses a drag and drop library that allows users to reorder items. Maybe it's time I took a look at Redux.

Comment: couldn't your parent handle that logic as well?

Comment: Your question gave me an idea! I added a 'currentItem' value to ObjectLists state which changed when an item was clicked, then I passed it to ObjectEditor as props and used componentWillReceiveProps. Thanks!